# how do you find the 2 numbers that have the maximum sum of digits and adding them can make up your desired number?

Tags: calculus

for example if I choose 35.

17+18=35
.....(1+7)+(1+8)=17....
among all the additions of 2 numbers that equal 35; choosing 18 and 17 gives us the maximum sum of the digits which is 17.

How can I find such 2 numbers for any given number?

I am aware that other numbers(for example 16+19) have the maximum sum of digits(17) as well......I don't care much about the numbers(meaning that I don't care if the solution gives me 16 and 19 or 18 ond 17 or...).... the main goal is to know what the maximum sum of the digits of any 2 numbers that make up my desired number is.

Comment: The optimal solution need not be unique, here $16+19$ gives the same sum $17$. Do you only want one optimal solution ?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Is there any reason to imagine that it has a simple solution (as opposed to, say, brute force checking)?

Comment: I am coding and this is what I need my code to achieve.....so I need to find the mathematic solution

Comment: Seems that making all digits $0$ except the first and subtracting $1$ gives one of the summands of an optimal solution. But I am not sure yet whether this always works.

Answer (score 1):

You can work from the ones digit upward.  Making the example $435$, the ones digits of the addends can add to $5$ or $15$.  You clearly want $15$, so can use $7+8$ or $6+9$.  Then the tens digits of the addends can add to $2$ or $12$.  You want $12$ rather than $2$, so something like $3+9$ or $6+6$ will work.  Keep going.